# How to modify the elements of an anonymous list within a for loop?

Tags: python

Is it possible to loop over a list that I define within the `for` statement and modify the original elements of that list or do I need a name / handle for that list to access its values by an index? I am aware of the alternatives that exist for lists with a variable name.

The following code does not alter a, b and c.

```
# in each iteration, this assigns item to the value behind a, b, or c
for item in [a, b, c]: 
    # this reassigns item to a new value, but there is no reference to a, b, or c 
    # (which I would like to have).
    item = some_function(item)
```

Simplified example (realistic example at the end):

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = 7

for item in [a, b, c]:
    item = item + 1

print("a: {}; b: {}; c: {}".format(a,b,c))
```

Output:

```
a: 1; b: 3; c: 7
```

Desired output:

```
a: 2; b: 4; c: 8
```

In my actual use case, `a`, `b` and `c` are numpy arrays and I want to clip their values like this:

```
for gradient in [a, b, c]:
    gradient = np.clip(gradient, -max_value, max_value)
```

#### Conclusion / Answer

Thanks to the [valuable input from bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48563488/1612420), I can now answer this question myself and add some explanations:

- The assignment operator only reassigns the loop variable to some new value and that does not alter the elements in the original list. There is a great article on how names / variables and assignments work in Python and I can strongly recommend it: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).
- In order to modify the original items in the list (either have them point to some new data or modify their data), one must either rely on methods that operate on the data in-place or hope for specific methods provided by the type of entry in the list ([see this helpful example from cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562810/1612420)).
- In my specific use case, I found the final solution in an optional `out` argument of the numpy.clip method:

  ```
  for gradient in [a, b, c]:
      np.clip(gradient, -max_value, max_value, out=gradient)
  ```

  However, the provided answers below, based on map() or list comprehension, are more universal.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This can't work, `int` is immutable. All you can do is reassign the variables themselves.

Comment: You're not modifying `a`. You're modifying a copy of its value  within an unnamed list, which you can't access later

Comment: @schwobaseggl the fact that ints are immutable is actually irrelevant here - as you mention, the op is not mutating the object but rebinding the loop variable. Doing the very same thing (rebinding the loop variable) with a list of dicts would yield the same result.

Comment: @cricket_007 there's no "copy" of anything involved here, and the OP is actually not _modifying_ anything - only rebinding a name.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers True. The immutability comment was to indicate that there are operations you could apply this way, e.g. `item.clear()` for a list of dicts, but assignment isn't one of them and immutable types do not even have any.

Comment: @bruno `[a, b, c]` becomes `[1,3,7]`, not a reference back to the variables. That's what I meant

Comment: @advay.umare, I added another example to show you my actual use case.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I probably made it worse by providing a simplified example with ints. In fact I want to modify numpy arrays.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry but you're still wrong.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I added a more realistic example at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it that way because the variable `item` is the one being updated and rebound within the loop body, and again after iteration. The values within the list itself aren't updated.

You could do this with a class so you have some object to refer back to after the loop

```
class Var():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def incr(self):
        self.x += 1
   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.x)

a = Var(1)
b = Var(3)
c = Var(7)

for item in [a, b, c]:
    item.incr()

print("a: {}; b: {}; c: {}".format(a,b,c))
```

Alternatively, you're looking for something like this

```
a, b, c = map(lambda x: x+1, [a, b, c])
```

Comment: I repeat: the op is __NOT__ "copying the value of a variable into a list".  Please learn what Python variables are before trying to explain them.

Comment: And there's no "unbound values" either, sorry. You seem to be quite confused about what Python variables are, and would certainly benefit from reading this : https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I understand well enough. I don't need to be lectured in box and pointer diagrams. All I want is to say the variable's values cannot be modified because the values within the list are not the same as the assigned loop variable

Comment: Sorry but the terms you keep on using clearly demonstrate that you do _not_ "understand well enough" and that youy would _really_ benefit from this little lecture.

Comment: Thank you for that example with the class, but the types of a, b and c are set and I also wanted a short and readable solution. However, the solution with `map` works fine for me. If you could modify your answer a bit, I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Thomas A class can wrap any type of variable. Even your numpy arrays. The `incr` function can do anything to update the value of `self.x`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
a, b, c = [np.clip(gradient, -max_value, max_value) for gradient in (a, b, c)]
```

would *mostly* do what you want - but beware that any other name referring to those arrays will still refer to the original (unclipped) values since `np.clip()` returns a new array.

For an in-depth explanation of why and hows, I strongly suggest you take time to read and fully understand [Ned Batcheler's excellent article on Python's names, values and bindings](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for that solution and the article! I summarized my conclusion in the original post. Thank you for your effort on pointing out the inexactness that occured in this topic with regards to copies. I think in this context it is very important to use exact formulations und your comments in addition with that article helped me to clearly understand at which point something is copied or reassigned or modified.